# Один запрос в две разные СУБД даёт разные ответы

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Есть две СУБД

- SQLite
- MS SQL

в каждой СУБД есть идентичная таблица с пользователями и таблица с ролями. Таблица с ролями имеет отношение "Один ко многим". В таблице с ролями две записи:

- Admins
- Clients

Таблица с клиентами имеет следующий вид:

- ClientsName
- ClientsPassword
- CurrentRoleId (внешний ключ на таблицу с
  ролями)

Есть простой запрос в базу:

```
select c.ClientName, r.Name from Clients c
LEFT JOIN Roles r
on c.CurrentRoleId = r.Id
WHERE c.ClientName = 'test2@mail.ru'
```

Ответ от СУБД я получаю разный. MS SQL отдаёт мне один правильный ответ:

```
ClientName    Name
test2@mail.ru Admin
```

SQLite отдаёт мне две одинаковые записи:

```
ClientName     Name
test2@mail.ru Admin 
test2@mail.ru Admin
```

Вопрос, с чем связанно такое поведение SQLite?

Comment: *с чем связанно такое поведение SQLite?* Это следствие различия исходных данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В табличке Clients в MSSQL одна запись с test2@mail.ru, в SQLite 2 записи с test2@mail.ru.

Comment: Это была действительно забавная ошибка. В базе Sqlite было две записи. DB Browser for SQLite для armbian почему то накладывал две строчки на одну. Как оказалось потом, в DB Browser for SQLite для Windows такой ошибки нет.